# Encryption Algorithms for VDI on cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-hosting, openstack

I don't need to explain the question but I am interested to know what the current encryption algorithms available for VDI (Virtual Disk images) on cloud like Open Stack or Amazon are.

Answer (score 0):

Both OpenStack and EC2 do not have any encryption for the VDI or AMI in EC2 terms. Its about how the image is bundled. To save space, some of them are tar zipped with sparse option set.